# Cancel/Transfer links or option in ical file

Tags: civievent

When we set up a civicrm event as public, it produces the Download iCal link and adding this link to the confirmation email as well which is good.

Is it possible to currently allow the user to cancel or transfer the registration from within the ical entry itself? Does a current extension help with this?

If not for an extension, what should we look at customising to enable this feature?

Any help is appreciated.